# Optimizing a SQL query

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have  a SQL query which I want to optimize as its used as inner query of a SP.

```
 SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentStartDate = Strt_Dt FROM   (
 SELECT 1 AS seq, Stat, Strt_Dt, Est_Hrs_Comp, EndDate, Tckt_Id, Envr
  FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e
  WHERE  e.tckt_id = @TicketID AND stat = 'INPR'
  UNION
  SELECT TOP 1 2 AS seq, Stat, Strt_Dt, Est_Hrs_Comp, EndDate, Tckt_Id, Envr
  FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e
  WHERE  e.tckt_id = @TicketID AND stat = 'CMPL'
  ORDER BY enddate DESC
  UNION
  SELECT TOP 1 3 AS seq, Stat, Strt_Dt, Est_Hrs_Comp, EndDate, Tckt_Id, Envr
  FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e
  WHERE  e.tckt_id = @TicketID AND stat = 'PLND'
  ORDER BY strt_dt
  UNION 
  SELECT 4 AS seq, 'UNP', NULL, NULL, NULL, tckt_id, 'Unplanned'
  FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e
  WHERE  e.tckt_id = @TicketID
) aa
ORDER BY aa.seq
```

Is there any better way to use this query. I need this as I have lot logic having same type.

Comment: Should the first sub-query have an `ORDER BY` clause?  Should the last sub-query have an additional `WHERE` clause, as otherwise it seems to also include all the records included in the preceding queries? And can you show some data to make it clear what is and is-not being excluded by using these `TOP 1`s?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... optimizations are highly vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: It would also be useful to add what you are trying to achieve in plain english - it's easier to help and solve an issue if you explain it. What is the query supposed to do, what does it not do? What are the performance problems? (I assume the UNIONS are the main issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a union on 4 results from the same table for the same criteria, can you not just use a CASE statement? e.g.

```
SELECT 
    CASE Stat
         WHEN 'INPR' THEN 1
         WHEN 'CMPL' THEN 2
         WHEN 'PLND' THEN 3
         WHEN 'Unplanned' THEN 4
         ELSE 0 -- Not sure what your 'ELSE' case would be
    END as Seq,
    etc....
FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e 
WHERE  e.tckt_id = @TicketID
```

You will still need case statements for all the fields which have logic, but it will include all data and will be a lot easier to read. Should also be a lot better for performance.

Comment: Sub-query one doesn't have an ORDER BY, sub-query two orders by `end_dt`, sub-query three orders by `strt_dt`.  This answer does not account for that aspect.  Yet ;)

Comment: Agreed - though I think it's difficult to see what the OP was getting at with the original query so I'm still not sure if this is a solution that can take into account what's needed

Comment: I ***think*** If there is an `In Progress` record, return it's start date.  Otherwise return the start date of the last to complete `Completed` record.  Otherwise return the start next of the next to start `Planned` records.  Otherwise return `NULL`.

Comment: I think the question needs clarification - I just ignored the outer 'TOP 1' and just went for trying to work on the inner routine, but maybe that was a mistake!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentStartDate = Strt_Dt FROM (
 SELECT 
        CASE stat WHEN 'INPR' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'CMPL' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'PLND' THEN 3
                    ELSE 4 END AS seq ,
        Stat, Strt_Dt, Est_Hrs_Comp, EndDate, Tckt_Id, Envr
  FROM   pipeline_rest_envr_info e
  WHERE  e.tckt_id = @TicketID ) aa
ORDER BY aa.seq
```

In fact it's the same answer as @Charleh

you don't need second and third `TOP 1` because you take only the first one from all union

Comment: Sub-query one doesn't have an ORDER BY, sub-query two orders by `end_dt`, sub-query three orders by `strt_dt`.  This answer does not account for that aspect.  Yet ;)

Comment: Yes , thanks , i didn't see `ORDER BY enddate DESC` and `ORDER BY strt_dt` in this case i think yours is the best method , it's easy to understand [and this is a solid point of view]

Comment: You mean you think the OPs is the best?  *(I have posted a comment asking for more details, but no answer.)*

Answer (score 2):

I the absence of a reply to my comment, I'll make a few assumptions...

A single `tckt_id` can have:

- Multiple `CMPL` items.  *(Completed?)*
- Just one `INPR` item.   *(In Progress?)*
- Multiple `PLND` items.  *(Planned?)*
- Multiple other items.   *(Unplanned?)*

You want the `strt_dt` of...

- The `INPR` item, if it exists.
- Otherwise, the last `CMPL` item, if it exists.
- Otherwise, the first `PLND` item, if it exists.
- Otherwise, `NULL`

```
SELECT
  TOP 1
  @current_start_date
  =
  CASE WHEN stat = 'INPR' THEN MIN(strt_dt)
       WHEN stat = 'CMPL' THEN MAX(strt_dt)
       WHEN stat = 'PLND' THEN MIN(strt_dt)
                          ELSE NULL
  END
FROM
  pipeline_rest_envr_info
WHERE
  tckt_id = @TicketID
GROUP BY
  stat
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN stat = 'INPR' THEN 1
       WHEN stat = 'CMPL' THEN 2
       WHEN stat = 'PLND' THEN 3
                          ELSE 4 END
```

This does have one additional assumption:

- Whatever `CMPL` item finished last, also started last

If that assumption is false, and if you have access to `ROW_NUMBER()`, you could try this instead...

```
WITH
  plus_sort_order
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY stat ORDER BY strt_dt ASC ) AS order_strt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY stat ORDER BY end_dt  DESC) AS order_end,
    *
  FROM
    pipeline_rest_envr_info
  WHERE
    tckt_id = @TicketID
)
SELECT
  TOP 1
  @current_start_date = strt_dt
FROM
  plus_sort_order
WHERE
  (order_strt = 1) OR (stat = 'CMPL' AND order_end  = 1)
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN stat = 'INPR' THEN 1
       WHEN stat = 'CMPL' THEN 2
       WHEN stat = 'PLND' THEN 3
                          ELSE 4 END
```

There are quite a few other ways.  But a lot depends on your data.  I'd advise you to play around with the ideas here and in other answers, and use explain/query plans to determine what indexes you need for each available option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to make `Temp Table` which is indexed as you want and then insert records in it from each `UNION`s.
It's some what faster then using of `UNION`s.